# iOS : What is the need of register cell before dequeuing in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I went through the discussion under these:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell

So, if we declare a cell prototype in the tableView itself (in the Interface Builder) then, we don't need to register cell under its identifier name. But, when the cell is constructed from a non-prototype class or nib then we need to register it.

Why would Apple want us to do so. Why can't it(a table view) dequeue (or recreate, if necessary) a cell without registering it?
For clarifying the question more: Why a different way of registering when we usually  straight away create objects from nib by loading them from nib.
Is this just to save the searching time of the class or nib. Is it to keep a buffer of the cells?

Answer (score 3):

You dequeue a cell using a reuse identifier string. In the case where there isn't an existing cell instance available for reuse, a new instance needs to be allocated. In order to allocate an inststance, the tableview needs to know what class it should be instantiating; a reuse identifier isn't enough.

When you use prototype cells in a storyboard scene, the storyboard registers the class against the reuse identifier for you. If you aren't using a storyboard then you need to perform that task.

You can use the "old" approach of getting `nil` when a cell isn't available for reuse and allocating a new cell instance yourself, but this requires you to write more code. This is also repetitive code if you have multiple cell types.

Even more code is required to extract a view from a nib, since they have a view controller as the root object.

Nibs in general are deprecated in favour of storyboard, and that is where Apple is providing new functions and capabilities

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the reuse queue is that we don't want to create new cells every time we need one. Think of scrolling a huge table view. Creating so many so cells so quickly is an expensive operation. Instead, the table view creates only so many cells it needs to display at a time and reuses others (rough idea).

The dequeue methods are there to check if any reusable cells are left before creating new ones.

What happens when the queue is empty? Now we do need to create a cell. We could create the cell manually which is totally fine. But it would be convenient if the table view would create the cell for us directly. That way we don't have to load it from a nib or instantiate it.

The point of the registering is that you tell the table view a) which cell class you want and b) how you want the cell to be created ([nib](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register) or [instantiated directly](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register)). Without registering, the table view wouldn't know how to create cells for you (often, we don't just want plain `UITableViewCell`s).

Additionally, a table view can contain multiple different cells. For example, an ad banner cell and main content cell. Registering different cells and reuse identifiers and offloading cell creation to the table makes this more convenient.

However, registering cells is **absolutely optional** and you can totally create cells manually. It is a convenience in that sense.  Look at the difference between [dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) and [`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell).